# How to raise the uninstall event in installer in c#

Tags: c#

I want to uninstall if a condition fails during installation process... how to do it?

```
protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    frmDataBaseSetup frmDataBaseSetup = new frmDataBaseSetup();
    frmDataBaseSetup.ShowDialog();
    if (frmDataBaseSetup.IsConnected)
    {
        // here i do something
        base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Can not continue without server information", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        base.Rollback(savedState);
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
    }            
}
```

This is not working when condition is false
please help me

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Installer page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.uninstall(VS.71).aspx

> SUMMARY: Notes to Inheritors:  When
>   you override the Uninstall method in a
>   derived class, be sure to call the
>   base class's Uninstall method first in
>   your derived method. The Uninstall
>   method is called to remove a
>   previously completed installation.